# On a certain morphism of schemes from affine space to projective space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm currently reading Ravi vakil's notes on algebraic geometry, and I'm completly stuck on a question and I would love for you all to shed some light on it. The question is:
"Make sense of the following sentence: '' $$\mathbb{A}^{n+1}_k \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$$ given by $$(x_0,x_1,..x_n) \rightarrow [x_0,x_1,..,x_n]$$ is a morphism of schemes.Caution: you can’t just say where points go; you have
to say where functions go. So you may have to divide these up into affines, and
describe the maps, and check that they glue"
OK, so I've tried to divide this up into affines, but I'm not sure exactly what this map is on these affina schemes to be honest. I feel that I have a clue, but I feel a bit uneasy about my arguments and my biggest problem is to check that they agree on overlaps. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing about this map is that it is defined globally.  So it suffices to find an open cover $\mathcal{U} = \{ U_i : i \in I \}$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $\pi \vert_{\pi^{-1}(U_i)} :\pi^{-1}(U_i) \rightarrow U_i$ is a morphism.  (Here, $\pi : \mathbb{A}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ denotes the given map.)  The fact that these maps agree on overlaps comes from the global definition of the map!  What has to be shown is that these maps are given by polynomial equations, i.e. that $\pi$ is *locally* given by polynomial maps.

The open cover to take is the standard one for projective space.  Let's check that you get a morpishm for $U = U_0 := \{ x = [x_0 : x_1 : \dots : x_n] \in \mathbb{P}^n : x_0 \neq 0 \}$.  It is easy to see that $\pi^{-1}(U) = \{ (x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{A}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} : x_0 \neq 0 \}$.  I claim that $U$ and $\pi^{-1}(U)$ are both affine varieties.  The coordinate ring of $U$ is $k[t_1,\dots,t_n]$, where $t_i = x_i / x_0$, while the coordinate ring of $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is $k[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n]_{x_0}$.  (This latter ring is the localization of $k[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n]$ at the multiplicatively closed subset $S = \{x_0^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.)

Let $\psi$ denote $\pi$ restricted to $\pi^{-1}(U)$.  To be a morphism, the map $\psi : \pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U$ must correspond to a ring homomorphism $\psi^* : k[t_1, \dots, t_n] \rightarrow k[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n]_{x_0}$.  I leave it as an exercise to check that $\psi^*(t_i) = x_i / x_0$.

Comment: It's been quite some time (just about 11 years)  but I can't help but say that you took the liberty to assume that $k$ is algebraicaly closed, hence identifying prime ideals with points. In there things are easy to understand and I doubt that Dedalus question was regarding this setting (despite him choosing you answer).

The problem with Vakil's question (which in the 2022 version of his notes is problem 7.3.F) is that it gives an identification in terms of points while people who understand the setting would expect identifications of prime ideals and that's the source of confusion. (1/2)

Comment: To elaborate, one needs to take a prime (affine) ideal and map it to the corresponding homogeneous ideal as in this answer on the same problem:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3250413/128787

Definitely that's the right setting for this problem and not varieties as Vakil hints a couple of pages later (ex. 7.3.O) the projective embedding defined by global sections for schemes over rings.