# Visualize the affine to projective map $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}_k-\{O\}$ to $\mathbb{P}^n_k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Classically, the natural map $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^{n+1}-\{O\} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C}$ maps every point in  $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^{n+1}-\{O\}$ to the affine line that contains it. For arbitrary $k$, there is also a natural map from $\mathbb{A}_k^{n+1}-\{O\}$ to $\mathbb{P}^n_k$, which could be defined by considering the map for different affine opens as $D(x_i)$ and it is answered in the following question.

[On a certain morphism of schemes from affine space to projective space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114165/on-a-certain-morphism-of-schemes-from-affine-space-to-projective-space)

So I have the question that is there a way to visualize this map like the classical one? I.e. given a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$, is there a straightforward way to find the homogeneous ideal it maps to?

For $k$-valued point in $\mathbb{A}_k^{n+1}-\{O\}$, is the answer the same as classical one? What can I state about other points?

edit: I think the image of $p$ is the largest homogeneous ideal contained in $p$.

Comment: It's just the homogenization of the ideal.

Comment: If $I$ is an ideal in $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, I know how to get its homogenization in $k[x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. But if $I$ is an ideal already in  $k[x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, how could we get its homogenization?

Comment: As in the question you've mentioned, you need and open cover of $\mathbb{P}^n$. On an affine chart it makes sense to see where ideals go...