# Classification of vector bundles of rank $n$ on $\mathbb{P}_k^{1}$ (Gortz's Algebraic Geometry)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, proof of the Theorem 11.51 and stuck at understanding existence part :

[image]

We will use the his book, Lemma 11.50 :

[image]

Here, $R^{+} := k[T], R^{-}:=k[T^{-1}], R^{\pm}:=k[T,T^{-1}]$.

Note that in his book, p.313, (11.17.1) there is a bijection.

$$A:= \{ \operatorname{isomorphism classes of vector bundles of rank n on} \mathbb{P}_k^{1} \} \xrightarrow{\psi} B:=GL_{n}(R^{+}) \backslash GL_{n}(R^{\pm})/GL_n(R^{-1})$$
(double quotient)

**C.f.** p.313 is as follows :

[image]

Now, to show the underlined statement, fix a vector bundle $\mathcal{E}$ of rank $n$ on $\mathbb{P}_k^{1}$. By the above Lemma 11.50, there exists a $\mathbf{d}:=(d_1 \ge d_2 \ge \cdots \ge d_n) \in (\mathbb{Z}^{n})_{+}$ such that $\psi(\mathcal{E})=GL_n(R^{+})T^{\mathbf{d}}GL_n(R^{-1})$.

**Let $X:= \mathbb{P}_k^{1}$ and $G:=GL_n(\mathcal{O}_X) : U \mapsto \operatorname{Aut}_{\mathcal{O}_U}(\mathcal{O}_X^{n}|_U) = GL_n(\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_U))$.**
Note that $\mathcal{U}:=(U_0, U_1)$, where $U_0:=\operatorname{Spec}k[T]$, $U_1:=\operatorname{Spec}k[T^{-1}]$, is an affine open cover of $X$ ( c.f. Gortz's Book, p.313 )

Q. Then $\psi ( \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{O}_{X}(d_i)) = GL_n(R^{+})T^{\mathbf{d}}GL_n(R^{-1})$ ? If so, then $\psi(\mathcal{E}) = \psi ( \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{O}_{X}(d_i))$ and $ \mathcal{E} \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{O}_{X}(d_i)$.

To show this question, I think that we can describe the above map $\psi$ more in detail.

**First**, let $A_{\mathcal{U}}:= \{\operatorname{isomorphism classes of locally free} \mathcal{O}_X-\operatorname{modules} \mathcal{E} \operatorname{of rank n such that} \mathcal{E}|_{U_i} \cong \mathcal{O}_{U_i}^{n} \operatorname{for all} i=0,1 \}$

Then $A = A_{\mathcal{U}}$ as in his book, p.313, (11.17) (True?).

Then I think that the $\psi$ is as follows :

$$ \psi : A=A_{\mathcal{U}} \to H^{1}(\mathcal{U},G) \xrightarrow{c_{G,\mathcal{U}}} \check{H}^{1}(\mathcal{U},G) \to B:=GL_{n}(R^{+}) \backslash GL_{n}(R^{\pm})/GL_n(R^{-1})  $$

Here, $H^{1}(\mathcal{U},G) := \{T\in H^{1}(X,G)  :  T \operatorname{is trivialized by} \mathcal{U} ; i.e., T(U_i) \neq \emptyset \operatorname{for all} i \}$ (Here $H^{1}(X,G)$ is the set of isomorphism classes of $G$-torsors (c.f. his book p.292)).
And the first map is $\mathcal{G} \mapsto \mathcal{Isom}(\mathcal{O}_X^{n},\mathcal{G})$ (c.f. his book p.295, (11.6)).
And the second map $c_{G,\mathcal{U}}$ is in p.294 above. And the third map is as p.313 (above image).

**Second**, let $\mathcal{G}:= \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{O}_X(d_i)$. Then by the first map, $\mathcal{G}$ sends to $\mathcal{Isom}(\mathcal{O}_X^{n} , \mathcal{G})$. And this sends to an element of $\check{H}^{1}(\mathcal{U},G)$ via the second map $c_{G,\mathcal{U}}$ as follows.

First, by the definition/or construction of $c_{G,\mathcal{U}}$ (c.f. his book p.294 above. If needed, I will upload the page), choose canonical(?) isomorphisms

$$t_0 : \mathcal{O}_{X}^{n}|_{U_0} \to \mathcal{G}|_{U_0} \in \mathcal{Isom}(\mathcal{O}_X^{n}, \mathcal{G}))(U_0) \neq \emptyset$$
$$t_1 : \mathcal{O}_{X}^{n}|_{U_1} \to \mathcal{G}|_{U_1} \in \mathcal{Isom}(\mathcal{O}_X^{n}, \mathcal{G}))(U_1) \neq \emptyset $$

Then since $G$ acts simply transitively (c.f. his book p.294 above and p.295, (11.6) ), there exists an element $g=g_{01} \in G(U_0 \cap U_1) =GL_{n}(R^{\pm})$ such that

$$ g_{01}t_1 = t_0$$

More precisely, $t_1|_{U_0 \cap U_1} \circ (g_{01})^{-1} =: g_{01}t_1|_{U_0 \cap U_1} = t_0|_{U_0 \cap U_1}$ (c.f. As the action of $G(U)$ on $\mathcal{Isom}(\mathcal{O}_X^{n}, \mathcal{G})(U)$, refer to his book p.295).

Note that $\{ g_{01}\}$ forms a $\check{\operatorname{C}}$ech $1$-cocycle of $G$ over $\mathcal{U}$ (c.f. his book, p.313). Then $c_{G, \mathcal{U}} (\mathcal{Isom}(\mathcal{O}_X^{n}, \mathcal{G})) = [ g_{01} ] \in \check{H}^{1}(\mathcal{U},G)$ (the cohomology class ; c.f. his book p.293 ).

**Third**, **my question is**, the cohomology class $[g:=g_{01}] \in \check{H}^{1}(\mathcal{U},G)$ sends via the third map of $\psi$ to $GL_{n}(R^{+})T^{\mathbf{d}}GL_{n}(R^{-})$ ?
; i.e.,

$$GL_n(R^{+})g_{01}GL_{n}(R^{-}) = GL_n(R^{+})T^{\mathbf{d}}GL_{n}(R^{-}) $$

in $B:= GL_n(R^{+}) \backslash GL_n(R^{\pm}) /GL_{n}(R^{-})$? If so, then $\psi ( \mathcal{G}) = GL_n(R^{+})T^{\mathbf{d}}GL_n(R^{-1})$ and we are done.

Note that to show the equality, it suffices to show that there exist
$h^{+} \in GL_n(R^{+})$ and $h^{-} \in GL_n(R^{-})$ such that $h^{+}g_{01}h^{-} = T^{\mathbf{d}}$. And is it true?

It seems that we need more information about $t_0, t_1$, and $g_{01}$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There is another thread where we discuss the construction of the projective line $C:=\mathbb{P}^1_R$ over any ring $R$ using geometric invariant theory: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603576/the-meaning-of-x-0-x-1-ldots-x-n-formed-by-projective-coordinates-on-pro/4603645#4603645

Comment: @hm2020 : Thanks for introduction to another approach. I think that I'll have to think about it a bit more.

Comment: the "double quotient" involves the group $GL(n)$ - one may try to use the same method to classify $H$-modules.

Comment: In this thread a character $\rho_m$ of $H$ constructs the rank one vector bundle $\mathbb{V}(\mathcal{O}(m)^*)$ over the complex numbers. Over more general rings the classification may become more complicated.   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599310/a-description-of-line-bundles-on-projective-spaces-mathcalo-mathbbpn/4601133#4601133

Comment: Thanks. I will refer to.

Comment: Anyway, I'll continue to try the approach taken in question above, because I want to understand the proof of the classification involving the primitive definitions of $H^{1}(\mathcal{U},G)$, $\check{H}^{1}(\mathcal{U},G)$, $c_{G,\mathcal{U}}$, etc.. :)

Comment: Any rank $n$ vector bundle/locally free sheaf $E$ on the projective line $C$ has the property that when you restrict it to the basic open sets $D(x_i)$ you you get a free module $E_i$ on a polynomial ring. When you restrict $E_i$ to the open set $D(x_0x_1)$ you get a transition matrix $M_E$ which is a rank $n$ matrix with coefficients in $k[t,1/t]$. The exercise/result says that this matrix may be "diagonalized" (in a generalized sense) with $t^i$ on the diagonal. The $t^i$ term corresponds to the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}(i)$.

Comment: @hm2020 : Uhm..I think that your transition matrix $M_E$ is related the $g_{01} \in GL_n(R^{\pm})$ in our question (same?) And the diagonalizability of the $g_{01}$ to $T^{\mathbf{d}}$  (our question) is equivalent to that "$GL_n(R^{+})g_{01}GL_{n}(R^{-}) = GL_n(R^{+})T^{\mathbf{d}}GL_{n}(R^{-}) $" And.. how can we show the diagonalizability?

Comment: @hm2020 : C.f. I think that more precisely, the diagonalizability means that there exist $h^{+} \in GL_n(R^{+})$ and $h^{-1}\in GL_n(R^{-})$ such that $h^{+}g_{01}h^{-} = T^{\mathbf{d}}$.

Comment: The problem with this site when you ask for details about a specific proof in a specific book, few people on the site have access to your book. This question is quite involved and technical and it requires knowledge on your book.

Comment: You should first explain to readers what you mean when you write $GL(\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Comment: O.K. I agree your comments. I see. And, $G:=GL_n(\mathcal{O}_X) : U \mapsto \operatorname{Aut}_{\mathcal{O}_U}(\mathcal{O}_X^{n}|_U) = GL_n(\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_U))$. I upload this as an EDIT.

Comment: It seems to me the definition $G(U):=Aut_{\mathcal{O}_U}(\mathcal{O}^n_U)$ defines a sheaf of non-abelian groups on $X$, hence you need a machinery defining the "cohomology of a sheaf of non-abelian groups". To my knowledge - there is such a "cohomology set" (there is no structure of abelian group on this "cohomology set") and it satisfies various general properties. Is this defined and studied in the Wedhorn book?

Comment: Yes. In p.292~296, he deals with such matariel : Eg. (11.5) Excursion : Torsors and non-abelian ($\check{C}$ech) cohomology, and (11.6) Vector bundles and $GL_n$-torsors. etc. He defined $H^{1}(X,G)$ , $\check{H}^{1}(X,G)$ only in his book, not $H^2, H^3, \cdots$ (by using the language of the derived functor). And..$H^{1}(X,G)$, $\check{H}^{1}(\mathcal{U},G)$ are just pointed sets(p.292~293), not an abelian group in general.

Comment: well, if someone having read the book reads this thread you might get an answer. Else, you should write carefully (including all definitions and where you explain the notation) an explicit example: Rank 2 bundles on the projective line $C$. How is $H^1(C, GL(2))$ defined as a set?

Comment: @hm2020 : O.K. whenever it is not enough, I'll continue to explain. In general, $H^{1}(X,G)$ is the set of isomorphism classes of $G$-torsors. (Gortz's book p.292). Let $G$ be a sheaf of groups on a topological space $X$. A $G$-torsor on $T$ (sheaf of sets on $X$) is a $G$-sheaf on $T$ such that (a) The group $G(U)$ acts simply transitively on $T(U)$ for every open subset $U\subseteq X$. (b) There exists an open covering $\mathcal{U}:=(U_i)_{i}$ of $X$ such that $T(U_i) \neq \emptyset$ for all $i$.