# 2 questions about the morphism $\mathbb{A}_k^{n+1}\backslash\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_k^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

An exercise in Ravi Vakil's algebraic geometry notes says "Make sense of the following sentence: $$\pi: \mathbb{A}_k^{n+1}\backslash\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_k^n$$ given by $$(x_0,x_1...,x_n)\mapsto [x_0,x_1...,x_n]$$ is a morphism of schemes.'"

I assume he means the morphism with $$Spec~ k[x_0,x_1,..,x_n]_{x_i}\rightarrow Spec~(k[x_0,x_1,..,x_n]_{x_i})_0 $$ induced by the inclusion $$(k[x_0,x_1,..,x_n]_{x_i})_0 \subset  k[x_0,x_1,..,x_n]_{x_i}$$ (where here $(k[x_0,x_1,..,x_n]_{x_i})_0$  is the degree zero elements of the ring $k[x_0,x_1,..,x_n]_{x_i}$).

**Is this correct?**

And I have another question:  I would have thought that the image $\pi(\mathfrak{p})$ of a point $\mathfrak{p}\in\mathbb{A}_k^{n+1}\backslash\{0\}$ could be described as follows:  If $x_i\notin \mathfrak{p}$, and  $$\mathfrak{p} = (f_1,...,f_m)$$ then we use $x_i$ to "homogenize" each $f_j$ -- that is we multiply each term of $f_j$ by some power of $x_i$ so that the resulting $f_j'$ is homogeneous. Then  $$\pi(\mathfrak{p}) = (f_1',...,f_m') $$ (Here we are thinking of $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ as the space of all homogeneous primes of $k[x_0,..,x_n]$ not containing the irrelevant ideal)

**Is this correct?**

This is my intuition, but I can't seem to prove it using the map in the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$Let's call $R=k[x_0,\dots x_n]$. We have $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}-\{0\} = \Spec(R)-(x_0,\dots x_n)$ and $\mathbb{P}^n$ corresponds to homogenous prime in $R$ different from $(x_0 \dots x_n)$.

Now, given a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \in \Spec(R)$ we can take its homogenization $\mathfrak{p}^h$ which is a prime homogenous ideal.

Now, the map $$ \pi: \mathbb{A}^{n+1}-\{0\} \to \mathbb{P}^n $$

$$\mathfrak{p} \to \mathfrak{p}^h$$ is at least well defined for topological spaces.

You can check that this map does exactly what you correctly pointed out at the end of your question. Now, to define the map between sheaves ,you can notice that $\pi(D(x_i))=D_+(x_0)$ where $D(x_i)=\{\mathfrak{p} \in \Spec(R) \mid x_i \not\in \mathfrak{p} \}$.

So, to let's say we want to define our morphism of sheaves $$\pi: \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n} \to \pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}-\{0\}} .$$

We start to define it restricted to the open sets $\pi(D_+(x_i))$ so that because of the observation above and the fact that both $U_i=D_+(x_i)$ and $V_i=D(x_i)$ are affine , it is sufficient to define a morphism of rings $ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(U_i) \to \pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}-\{0\}}(V_i)$.

Now, with the standard identification, this is the standard morphism of immersion you pointed out.

It's a standard verification that these morphisms patch locally so that we get the global $\pi$ between sheaves we wanted.

Let's look at what happens to primes here: let $i=0$ for the sake of simplicity. So we have $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}|_{U_0} \cong \Spec\left(k\left[\dfrac{x_i}{x_0}\right]\right)$. This isomorphism goes like this: you take a homogenous prime $\mathfrak{p}$, you localize it in $x_0$ and then you take the degree zero part.

To get what Vakil is saying, try to look a what happens at maximal ideals.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  So this is my problem: If I'm correct that $\pi$ is locally induced by that inclusion of rings, then to find $\pi(\frak{p})$  I just need to find the degree-zero part $\mathfrak{p}_0$ of $\mathfrak{p}\in Spec~k[x_0,x_1,..,x_n]_{x_i}$.  It seems like I want $\mathfrak{p}_0 = (f_1(\frac{x_0}{x_i},\frac{x_1}{x_i},...,\frac{x_n}{x_i}),...,f_n(\frac{x_0}{x_i},\frac{x_1}{x_i},...,\frac{x_n}{x_i}))$  (-- that is each generator $f'$ of $\frak{p}_0$ is just  gotten from $f$ by replacing $x_j$ with $x_j/x_i$)  then I would be happy.

Comment: But I don't see why the degree zero part of a prime in $k[x_0,x_1,..,x_n]_{x_i}$ should be gotten this way.  For instance I was thinking that if $\frak{p}$ is a principle ideal generated by a non-homogeneous element, it seems like it's degree zero part should actually be zero.

Comment: I edited tried to being clearer. To get what is really happening you should be cautious wiht identification you make when restricting to $D_+(x_i)$

Comment: Thanks again, and sorry if I'm missing the point.  I understand how the morphism is defined -- define it on affines as morphisms induced by inclusions of rings and then check that everything glues.  I just don't understand how the resulting map of prime ideals is "homogenization".  If $\mathfrak{p}_0:=\mathfrak{p} \cap (k[x_0,...,x_n]_{x_i})_0 = (f_1(\frac{x_0}{x_i},..., \frac{x_n}{x_i}),...,f_n(\frac{x_0}{x_i},..., \frac{x_n}{x_i}))$, then it's clear that it is homogenization. but it's not clear to me that $\mathfrak{p}_0$ has this form.

Comment: ($f_n$ should probably be $f_m$ since $n$ is already being used)